# Is there a simpler form for this Meijer G function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

On the mathematica Mathworld website, it's easy to find the expression for the Meijer G function. However, it is less easy to see if it has some simpler form in terms of other known functions. The specific case I would like to simplify is

`MeijerG[{{}, {3 + a, -b}, {{0, 1}, {}}, x^2]`

with $a\geq b\geq 0$ and $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x\in(0,1)$. If it helps, I have reason to believe it's related to the hypergeometric function $x^2 {_2 F_1}(-(1 + a);2 + b;2; x^2)$, as they both solve the same differential equation.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=MeijerG%5B%7B%7B%7D%2C+%7B3+%2B+a%2C+-b%7D%7D%2C+%7B%7B0%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B%7D%7D%2C+x%5E2%5D

Comment: Thanks! Funny how mathematica doesn't do this sort of simplification automatically, even after full simplify!